# Solr, select where in select

Tags: apache, select, solr

I'm trying to do a query with a select in another.

I would like to do something like:

```
select?q=*:* AND id_user=5&fl=id_other    
select?q=test AND -id(the result of the other select)&fl=id
```

So:

```
select?q=test AND -id(select?q=* AND id_user=5&fl=id_other)&fl=id
```

Is it possible? Or I have to do two separates selects?

```
$ids = select?q=*:* AND id_user=5&fl=id_other
$result = select?q=test AND -id(implode(' AND ', $ids))&fl=id
```

Thanks!

Comment: First off you should ask yourself why you need that. Looks like you're querying a relational database using SQL, but you're using Solr.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nested query support in Solr. You can `_query_` parameter to embed query into another. Check [this](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/03/31/nested-queries-in-solr/) tutorial for more information.